# Convert binary / unicode string to image

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using a library to recieve attachments (image) from salesforce using OAuth and a proxy. Without the library (and the proxy) I am able to the same using XHR, but I have to use the library because I need the proxy.

In chrome debugger I can see image is downloaded fine, but I can't get it to work in my code. Data looks like:

[image]

So far methods I have tried:

1. `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(file.body)));`- produces a base64 that does not work. decoding it using online tools gives me back the same string.
2. `escape(file.body)` - using this as base64 also does not work.
3. Converting to a blob.

   `var blob = new Blob([file.body], {type : "image/png"});
   urlCreator.createObjectURL(blob);`

   The url it points to displays nothing, and if I remove `{type : "image/png"}` the url points to a page displaying same binary string.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a binary so we can try to replicate it?

Comment: here it is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Varun-garg/CordovaPractice/master/5b90dc1c-7b81-4038-9477-7ea54617bb12.jpeg

Comment: and the respnse I get from chrome developer tools is: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Varun-garg/ed23e7e2259da052f09f3f6929087615/raw/b75388019cad8a9c58ab0b6663163ce025af7d48/response . It decodes fine online.

Comment: What is the type of `file`? Is it an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: typeof just shows `object` for `file` and `string` for `file.body`

Comment: saw this thread bumped recently. looking back now I guess there could be a bug in chrome dev tools while decoding base64 - such as spliting/joining/encoding etc. should have tried with `curl -v` to get a better idea

Answer (score 1):

Long story short this looks like someone read the image with readAsText() which mangles ("interprets") binary into utf8, instead of utf16. You need to get the server to return the data in arraybuffer or blob format ideally, or even base64, these preserve binary.

Long version with snippet. (those question marks symbols in the snippet show the lost information, compare it to the binary where they are not question marks in utf16):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523118/2962797

Answer (score 0):

I would create an `<img />` element, equal its `src` attribute to the image data you received. Now you have the image.

If you want to extract it or convert it to PNG, I would apply this another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) process.

Comment: You mean directly setting binary string as src? that did not work, and gave `GET http://localhost:8000/%EF%BF%BDPNG%1A%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD ....net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: @VarunGarg I [tried](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGwyWY) to do it and it worked. And you provided me with the string.

Comment: That string is what I see in chrome dev tools, not the one I got from the library (please see the sreenshot.).

Comment: @VarunGarg Ok, I understand. But that image is JPEG, and when you tried to decode it in the third method you used, you tried to decode a PNG one.

Comment: It is actually a png, the `content type` returned here is wrong (jpeg), but that is just for this case only. In other cases it is correct, such as `image/png` .